# after summer 20 lightning data table top borders are missing

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

in summer20 they added cell/column border for lightning datatable, after column border added it looks awkward.

**in Summer20 SB**
[image]

**before summer20 SB**
[image]

is there anyway to add top border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i added top border explicitly in lightning data table class `slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-scrollable_x slds-border_top`.

```
<lightning:datatable aura:id = "cusDT"
                                        class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-scrollable_x slds-border_top"
                                         columns="{! v.Datacolumns }"
                                         data="{!v.data}"
                                         keyField="id"
                                         showRowNumberColumn="true"
                                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                         onrowaction="{!c.rowactionhandler}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: In lwc I needed to put the datatable into a div and give the class property to that div.

Comment: @Schnap Please post as a new question. so all of them can hep

Comment: It's not a question. It just wasn't working when using the class attribute in lightning:datatable, so I added in case that solution isn't working for future readers as well. I had to wrap it in a div and use slds-border_top there. In fact I later upgraded to slds-box_border to enclose completely.